# What happened when redirecting output of tail -f + grep/awk?

Tags: linux, shell, awk

i have a **growing** test.log like this:

```
abc ID1
aaa ID2
abb ID3
ccc ID4
```

and i want to **save** corresponding ID of ".*a.*b.*" **to log file** like this

```
$ tail -f test.log | grep --line-buffered '.*a.*b.*' | awk '{print $2}' > a_ID.log
```

i tried

```
$ tail -f test.log | grep '.*a.*b.*'
$ tail -f test.log | grep --line-buffered '.*a.*b.*' > a.log
```

both work fine, but what should be done with awk?

```
# No output
$ tail -f test.log | awk '{print $2}'
# Obviously nothing in ID.log
$ tail -f test.log | awk '{print $2}' > ID.log
```

does awk have a '--line-buffered' like grep? how about sed?

Comment: This is discussed at length in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/009 but the short of it is that Awk does not need to be unbuffered in this scenario.  Something else is wrong.  Still, read that FAQ page.

Comment: Notice also that `grep '.*a.*b.*'` is better written `grep 'a.*b'`.

Comment: thx a lot, i'll read it

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
$ tail -f test.log | awk '{ print $2; fflush(); }'
```

from the man page it said it will flush the stdout.

Comment: my awk is mawk, not GNU-awk, that's why it fails. but thx any way.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work with mawk.

```
$ tail -f test.log | awk -W interactive '{print $2}' > ID.log
```

The `-W interactive` makes mawk write unbuffered to stdout.